# change ftp to sftp in a shell script

Tags: bash

I have this shell script which transfers CSV files to another server using the FTP service, and I need to change this service to SFTP. Can anyone help me?

```
ftp -inv  >$FTP_LOG_FILE <<EOF   
open $FTP_HOST
user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD
lcd $REPORT_LOCAL_SOURCE
cd $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
mput *$FILE_TYPE
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use public key authentication? That makes it pretty easy - no password required.

Also, personal preference - ftp gives you no way to reasonably interact with the file transfers and react to misbehavior. Try `scp`.

Assuming automatic public-key authentication and the same vars you used above -

```
scp $REPORT_LOCAL_SOURCE/*$FILE_TYPE $FTP_USERNAME@$FTP_HOST:$DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/
```

or, with shorter names...

```
if scp ldir/*$ext $me@$host:$dir/
then echo "No errors"
else echo "There were errors"
fi
```

Generally, try to *never* use all cap vars.

Comment: scp also gets rid of the HERE document and the FTP command details in it.